# Serialize list to an existing .Json file, using a datagridview

Tags: c#, json, datagrid

I have a deserialized json file output directly to a `DGV`, and visible to the end user in a `DGV`. when they are done using the software and close out, I would like to serialize the updated `DGV` to my json file.

when I deserialized this json file the code is as follows:

**CODE**

```
    var v = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ToolJson> 
    (File.ReadAllText(@"\testLibrary.json"));

        //set DGV source to our datums 
        toolDataGridView.DataSource = v.Datums.Cast<IInteresting> 
        ().ToList();
```

and when the form is closed i want to read the DGV back into my json file, in the exact same format it is already. below is snippet of the json file. all i am doing with the DGV is keeping track of Quantities, last employee used and if the tool needs returned. basically 5 new entries to the json file. top level properties.

***Json File***

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "BMC": "carbide",
        "Cost": 0,
        "Employee": "",
        "GRADE": "Mill Generic",
        "Location": "",
        "description": "5/8-11\"",
        "geometry": {
            "CSP": false,
            "DC": 0.433,
            "HAND": true,
            "LB": 2,
            "LCF": 0.5,
            "NOF": 4,
            "NT": 1,
            "OAL": 5,
            "SFDM": 0.625,
            "TP": 0.0909091,
            "shoulder-length": 1.969,
            "thread-profile-angle": 60
        },
        "guid": "0112c196-8a79-421d-8dda-d4aa964aa6d7",
        "holder": {
            "description": "Maritool CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "guid": "e800051b-e2d6-4699-a2b6-dad6466a0a0c",
            "last_modified": 1485790626152,
            "product-id": "CAT40-ER32-2.35",
            "product-link": "",
            "segments": [
                {
                    "height": 0.148,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.5,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.836,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.97,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.97
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.176,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.57,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.57
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.09,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.57,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.425,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.05,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.85
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.03,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.442,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.145,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.079,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.215
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.118,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.215,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.215
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.079,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.215,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.143,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.502
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.03,
                    "lower-diameter": 2.502,
                    "upper-diameter": 2.442
                },
                {
                    "height": 0.125,
                    "lower-diameter": 1.75,
                    "upper-diameter": 1.75
                }
            ],
            "type": "holder",
            "unit": "inches",
            "vendor": "Maritool"
        },
        "onHandQty": 0,
        "OrderQty": 5,
        "post-process": {
            "break-control": false,
            "comment": "",
            "diameter-offset": 17,
            "length-offset": 17,
            "live": true,
            "manual-tool-change": false,
            "number": 17,
            "turret": 0
        },
        "product-id": "GMDTTM58-11UN4FL",
        "product-link": "6010",
        "start-values": {
            "presets": [
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.012242786571039,
                    "f_z": 0.0031,
                    "guid": "eac33213-4083-35b8-afe3-17bd42a249f0",
                    "n": 4410.76054758139,
                    "n_ramp": 44110,
                    "name": "1018",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 499.9999999999994,
                    "v_f": 54.6934307900093,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 54,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 54,
                    "v_f_plunge": 54,
                    "v_f_ramp": 54
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.010769117817118,
                    "f_z": 0.0028,
                    "guid": "f35f5601-68a9-477b-b4b0-2ffeedb3bef1",
                    "n": 1764.3042190325598,
                    "n_ramp": 1764,
                    "name": "4140",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 200,
                    "v_f": 19.7602072531647,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 19,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 19,
                    "v_f_plunge": 19,
                    "v_f_ramp": 19
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.012091641057817,
                    "f_z": 0.0031,
                    "guid": "b118ce46-da35-4ed6-9806-b98e05ffe077",
                    "n": 2646.45632854884,
                    "n_ramp": 2646,
                    "name": "Tool Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 300,
                    "v_f": 32.8160584740056,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 32,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 32,
                    "v_f_plunge": 32,
                    "v_f_ramp": 32
                },
                {
                    "description": "",
                    "f_n": 0.01118476797848,
                    "f_z": 0.0028,
                    "guid": "0e1767f5-b0ef-422f-b49d-6cb8c3eb06ed",
                    "n": 3308.0704106860494,
                    "n_ramp": 3308,
                    "name": "Stainless Steel",
                    "tool-coolant": "flood",
                    "use-stepdown": false,
                    "use-stepover": false,
                    "v_c": 375,
                    "v_f": 37.0503885996837,
                    "v_f_leadIn": 37,
                    "v_f_leadOut": 37,
                    "v_f_plunge": 37,
                    "v_f_ramp": 37
                }
            ]
        },
        "stockQty": 5,
        "type": "thread mill",
        "unit": "inches",
        "vendor": "Gorilla Mill"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearing accompanying text, i think i understand where the difficulty lied and indeed it is an exotic datatype we need to Use, unless there Is only one list in the json, in which case you can simply add table to named dataset "Tool" and serialize that, I've included both

```
public partial class frmWithGrid : Form
{                 
    public frmWithGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string myDynamicJSON = "Imagine your testLibraryJson loaded here or later but before next line";
        DataTable convertedToTableToolData = ConvertToTableToolData(myDynamicJSON);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = convertedToTableToolData;
        //dataGridView1.DataMember = we're not storing it in a dataset so we can ignore this one
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;   
        
        //TODO: Add bla bla to setup UI of cause, suppose you're able to navigate rows etc.
    }

    DataTable ConvertToTableToolData(string jsonSource)
    {
        //TODO: Insert own convertion code here, which seems to be in place
        return new DataTable(); // instead of this
    }

    private void btnUserIsDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Obviously this shouldn't be directly in an event handler

        //Either you have many lists
        dynamic x = new ExpandoObject();
        var editedTable = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        //Will ignore that your OrderQty maybe wasn't originally part of data structure, because it may have been
        //and it doesn't change anything with the principle, and adds needless complexity
        var propertiesDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)x;
        propertiesDictionary.Add("Tool", editedTable);

        //TODO: Add other sets to json if applicable

        string serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);



        //or just one
        var ds = new DataSet("Tool");
        ds.Tables.Add(editedTable.Clone());
        serialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
    }
}
```

Comment: the microsoft doc is binding to SQL. which gets very unclear to me. how can i just bind my datagridtable to the existing datatable, and then serialize that?

Comment: @JoeFisher You are decided on using a datatable? i was suggesting skipping that as that is the manual part which takes good work, but will update with how to use datatable with binding source example

Comment: obviously you can serialize both tooldtaSet and tooldataSet.Tables["Tool"]

Comment: I made changes to the datagridview. does the data in DGV directly corelate to my datatable? I expected i needed to send data from gridview back to datatable, then serialize. also is it just as simple as that one serialize line? i dont need a foreach kind of loop to build a list first?

Comment: Yes, it can, of cause you have to set autogenerate column on or have correlating columns defined in case data is not clear always which type. There are some cases when you want to support edit,insert etc where having an actual bindingsource can be practical though.
Newtonsoft.Json serialize table rows int an array of elements which is excatly the same as a list of elements serialized so i suspect You do not have to do anything special. If You deserialize you may have to be specific depending on nullable fields, such will guess on string which more often then not isn't correct

Comment: I apologize if I come off wrong here, but I still don't exactly understand. If all I do is serialize this object back to the file, well its an empty object right now. I'm not sure how to loop through a datatable and commit the values to my object.

Comment: also there is no pmethod called DataBind(); for a datagridview

Comment: @JoeFisher well commit to where of cause becomes of relevance, but say your GridView.datasource is populated with a table and you have databound to it, now changing it will change what is is, right. try it out. so depending on Your interaction with you r gridivew this will possibly change in different ways which is you hooking up to perform such changes, depending on how rich your interaction is, it could be an advantage to put the table into a bindinglist for instance because it has specific events which more easily can be wired up, but you know your use case  and what is required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239404/discussion-between-joe-fisher-and-t-nielsen).

Comment: sorry yes, the databind is not implemented in the windows.forms edition, but it has datasource and datamember, try those ... i'll update example

Comment: @JoeFisher i am a bit in transit at the moment, have to clap the laptop but think i will update with more working example, for fun. Doesn't seem to entirely get u there with general nodges to very full pages, but it will be a little while before i can update

Comment: I am in absolutely no rush. thanks for the help i will check out datamember!

Comment: @JoeFisher ok, i've replaced solution generals with concrete sketched example with the juicy bits implemented depending on your json i think this was your challenge? Please clarify if not

Comment: seems my code here is outdated. as now i have gotten rid of the datatable alltogether. deserialize the json file to an object. and then bind that object directly to my DGV. that is where i am at now. doesnt seem to want to serialize still. probably best to do some editing to this question as alot of content changed.